# unable to add data to a table in mysql, Error Code: 1054

Tags: mysql, table, errors

**##Created table using the following line:**

```
create table sales (
  product_id int, 
  sell_price float, 
  quantity int, 
  state varchar(20) );
```

**##Tried to input values using the following line**

```
insert into sales values 
(121, 320.0, 3, ‘California’), 
(121, 320.0, 6, ‘Texas’), 
(121, 320.0, 4, ‘Alaska’), 
(123, 290.0, 2, ‘Texas’), 
(123, 290.0, 7, ‘California’), 
(123, 290.0, 4, ‘Washington’), 
(121, 320.0, 7, ‘Ohio’), 
(121, 320.0, 2, ‘Arizona’), 
(123, 290.0, 8, ‘Colorado’);
```

**## Following Error popped up:**

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '‘California’' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

Use apostrophe (`'`) or double quote (`"`) to quote strings, not left or right single quotation marks.  (`‘`)